# TypeError: Cannot create property 'next' on number '8080'

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am a newbie to node.js and was trying to create a sample web server with the code below but I got this error instead. could someone please point out/ explain what went wrong?

> req.next = next;
>            ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot create property 'next' on number '8080'

```html
// Setup empty JS object to act as endpoint for all routes
projectData = {};

// Require Express to run server and routes
const express = require('express');
// Start up an instance of app
const app = express();
/* Middleware*/
//Here we are configuring express to use body-parser as middle-ware.
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Cors for cross origin allowance
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
// Initialize the main project folder
app.use(express.static('Weather-Journal-App'));


// Setup Server
const port = 8080;
const server = app(port, listening)
function listening(){
    console.log(`App server is up and running on localhost: port ${port}`);
};
```

Comment: Are you sure that  port `8080` is open and free to use ? can you try with `const port = 3000;` for example (don't forget to open this port if you use a firewall)

Comment: I doubt it has anything to do with port access. It’s more likely an API usage error. Verify that’s valid usage for the targeted version, following examples. Something is incorrectly forwarding the port value, which I suspect is incorrectly supplied. (Isn’t there a “start” or some such?)

Comment: Also, make sure to show a *minimal* failing case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want to use:

```
app.listen(port, listening)
```

instead of `app(port, listenting)`

Comment: Thank you. This combined with changing my port to "3000" worked.